# JTA transactions involving spring and non-spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, atomikos, bitronix

By using an external jta manager like atomikos or bitronix, is it possible to combine a spring transaction and a non-spring transaction? If possible, do I still need to annotate the method as transactional - what if the transactions span across methods or classes?

Comment: What do you mean about combining `a spring transaction and a non-spring transaction`? What is a `non-spring transaction`?

Comment: I have an application that involves transactions using spring and jta. I've another library that accepts entity manager factory (non-spring) and performs transactions using a different data source. Just by using jta based transaction manager - is it possible to achieve roll back etc if either one of the side fails?

Answer (score 0):

Then you should allow the other library use the same JTA library which you configured in Spring with either Bitronix or Atomikos.

This way, you have a a [JTA transcation manager configured in Spring](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) and a single JTA DataSource which you need to pass to the outer library via the `hibernate.connection.datasource` configuration property.